# How to access my web api through subdomain

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently doing a web API using .NET. I'm currently testing it on insomnia and postman and my issue is:

If I make a request let's say something like HTTP://1.2.3.4:5000/controller it works like a charm. But now what I'm trying to do is access through a domain like http://api.mydomain.com/controller.

The subdomain redirects to the IP address of the google cloud VM where the API is mounted (http://sub.dom.com => http://1.2.3.4:5000)

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUserRepo _userRepo;

    public UserController(IUserRepo userRepo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST2");
        _userRepo = userRepo;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return _userRepo.Get();
    }
```

It only works when I comment or remove the `[Authorize]` part. If I add something like `[AllowAnonymous]` on top of the `[HttpGet]` it doesn't work.

I'm currently using JWT Bearer token to allow access and is working when I access from the IP address, as I said.

Can anyone help me or point me to the documentation to make this happen?

This is my startup.cs

```
namespace sinba_backend
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration; 
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers();

            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ConnSettings));
            services.Configure<ConnSettings>(appSettingsSection);
            services.AddSingleton<IConnSettings>(serviceProvider =>
                serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConnSettings>>().Value);
            var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<ConnSettings>();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.SecretCredentials);

            services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
            {
                authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(jsonWebToken =>
            {
                jsonWebToken.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                jsonWebToken.SaveToken = true;
                jsonWebToken.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                };
            });
            
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepo,UserRepo>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(policy =>
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin().
                    AllowAnyHeader().
                    AllowAnyMethod()
            );
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it's something network related, but I don't think so since I have access when I remove the `[Authorize]` part.

Thanks.

Edit:

Just to point out
I have http://api.mydomain.com/auth, if credentials are correct it sends a token back to me, then I use that token for all operations, but that only works when I'm accessing through the IP address, when I use the domain it send me `404 Not Found` or `Unauthorized`, even to anonymous routes, when I remove the `[Authorize]` part the anonymous routes start to work

As I previously said if I use my browser and put http://api.mydomain.com/ it redirects to http://1.2.3.4:5000/

Comment: Just for clarification, are you actually using some sort of HTTP "Redirect" to the IP address or are you using DNS CNAME?

Comment: @BryanLewis
I am using a dns domain, a friend lent me his and I decided to give it a try.

I have tried visible redirection, where the domain changes to the destination ip and I have also tried invisible redirection, where the domain name remains.
My provider is ovh.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. The problem was that when I was redirecting the destination URL wasn't obtaining the sent headers so `Authorization: Bearer token` was never reaching the endpoint.

To solve this I had to configure a DNS zone in my Google Cloud Project where the VM was allocated, the domain was the [api.mydomain.com](https://api.mydomain.com), and then it will give you their DNS NS Servers URLs.

After that, I simply add those DNS Servers URLs inside the domain configuration area point a new redirection to my VM external IP address, and there you have it, all headers reach destination correctly since they are going directly to your host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Authorize, you need to pass a token to the web api. Since your call works when you comment out [Authorize], it appears that you:

1. Are not passing the token to the controller, or
2. your token is from your local domain.

Your solution should be to call your login routine on http://api.mydomain.com/login,
get a token, and use that token in your postman call to http://api.mydomain.com/controller.

Comment: Hi that exactly is my problem i have http://api.mydomain.com/auth, if credentials are correct it sends a token back to me, then i use that token to all operations, but that only works when I'm accessing through the IP address, when i use the domain it send me not found or unauthorized, even to anonymous routes, when i remove the Authorize part the anonymous routes start to work

Comment: Maybe your routing is not properly set up? Add [RoutePrefix("/User")] right above UserController class declaration, and then put [Route("GetAll")] above the GetAll() function. Remove [Route("[controller]")] from above UserController class. Then you should be able to call like this:  http://api.mydomain.com/user/getall

Comment: It didn't work but I'm starting to think that this issue goes way beyond .NET code
It might be something network related. I'll go to read some documentation about the way redirections and DNS works, maybe I'm missing something. Thanks.